# How to sort cells in collectionView from newest to oldest. Realm, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, realm

These are my realm classes and functions:

```
class RealmItems: Object {
    @objc dynamic var header = String()
    @objc dynamic var specification = String()
    @objc dynamic var day = Int()
    @objc dynamic var month = Int()
    @objc dynamic var deadline = String()
    @objc dynamic var status = String()
}

class RealmModel {
    
    static let shared = RealmModel()
    private let realm = try! Realm()
    
    func addTask(headerTask: String, specificationTask: String, dayTask: Int, monthTask: Int, deadlineTask: String, statusTask: String) {
        
        let new = RealmItems()
        
        new.header = headerTask
        new.specification = specificationTask
        new.day = dayTask
        new.month = monthTask
        new.deadline = deadlineTask
        new.status = statusTask
        
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(new)
        }
    }
    
    func deleteTask(name: RealmItems) {
        try! realm.write {
            realm.delete(name)
        }
    }
    
    func getTasks() -> [RealmItems] {
        
        var arrayTasks: [RealmItems] = []
        
        for task in realm.objects(RealmItems.self) {
            arrayTasks.append(task)
        }
        return arrayTasks.sorted{$0.day > $1.day}
    }    
}
```

function `getTasks()` doesn't work the way i want it works. Now collection shows oldest cells higher than newest - that's wrong. I want to newest were higher than oldest

Comment: Any serious database provides custom predicates to fetch data sorted. It's more efficient to use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to be aware of.

First, read [Realm Objects Are Lazily Loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66603093/modeling-sub-collections-in-mongodb-realm-sync/66643920#66643920) e.g. don't cast them to an array or sort them using Swift functions. Well, you can but it can lead to other issues so best to avoid that unless there's a specific use case that requires it.

Secondly, Realm Results do not have a guaranteed order unless you specify that order. On the other hand, a List object maintains it's order.

Ordering a Results collection is simple, and actually keeps the objects in the results in order as object properties change, for example

```
let orderedResults = realm.objects(RealmItems.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "day", ascending: false)
```

Will load all of the RealmItems objects sorted by `day`, descending (e.g. 20th will be at the top and the 1st will be at the bottom)and the results will maintain their order. e.g. if a day changes, it will auto sort within the list. Pretty magical, huh?